# Is dispose called down to the bottom via yield return?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, dispose, yield-return

I give silly examples for simplicity.

```
IEnumerable<T> Silly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    foreach(var x in source) yield return x;
}
```

I know that this will be compiled into a state machine. but its also similar to

```
IEnumerable<T> Silly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using(var sillier = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while(sillier.MoveNext()) yield return sillier.Current;
    }
}
```

Now consider this usage

```
list.Silly().Take(2).ToArray();
```

Here you can see that `Silly` enumerable may not be fully consumed, but `Take(2)` it self will be fully consumed.

**Question:** when dispose is called on `Take` enumerator will it also call dispose on Silly enumerator and more specifically `sillier` enumerator?

My guess is, compiler can handle this simple use case because of `foreach` but what about not so simple use cases?

```
IEnumerable<T> Silly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using(var sillier = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // move next can be called on different stages.
    }
}
```

Will this ever be a problem? because most enumerators don't use unmanaged resources, but if one does, this can cause memory leaks.

---

If dispose is not called, How do i make disposable enumerable?

---

An Idea: there can be a `if(disposed) yield break;` after every `yield return`. now dispose method of silly enumerator will just have to set `disposed = true` and move the enumerator once to dispose all the required stuff.

Comment: What makes you think `Take` will dispose the enumerator? A `TakeIterator` (which is what `Take` returns) doesn´t do much as of the source-code. In particular it does not dispose anything.

Comment: Why not write your own `IEnumerator` and see if `dispose` is called on it when you use it like that?

Comment: @HimBromBeere What makes you think that take *doesn't* dispose of the enumerator that it creates?  If it didn't, that would be a bug in its code, and you should report it to MS.  Of course, looking at the source code, it never creates an enumerator that isn't disposed.

Comment: @Servy you are right. I just didn't want to get in the rabbit hole :)

Comment: This is the sort of thing where it's instructive to compile your examples and then see what the compiler has pushed into the implementing class for the enumerator via a decompiler. You can see all of the machinery for e.g. handling `Dispose` to make sure that the logical `finally` for `using` or explicit `finally`'s get called.

Comment: I'm confused.  `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` returns an `IEnumerator` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2).  `IEnumerator` doesn't extend `IDisposable` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Where does `Dispose` fit into all this?  I didn't look at the generic version, but I'm assuming it's the same basic structure.  OK, `IEnumerator<T>` is disposable.  Wow, I can check off the "learn something new" box for the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# compiler takes care of a *lot* for you when it turns your iterator into the real code. For instance, here's the `MoveNext` which contains the implementation of your second example<sup>1</sup>:

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    try
    {
        switch (this.<>1__state)
        {
            case 0:
                this.<>1__state = -1;
                this.<sillier>5__1 = this.source.GetEnumerator();
                this.<>1__state = -3;
                while (this.<sillier>5__1.MoveNext())
                {
                    this.<>2__current = this.<sillier>5__1.Current;
                    this.<>1__state = 1;
                    return true;
                Label_005A:
                    this.<>1__state = -3;
                }
                this.<>m__Finally1();
                this.<sillier>5__1 = null;
                return false;

            case 1:
                goto Label_005A;
        }
        return false;
    }
    fault
    {
        this.System.IDisposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So, you'll notice that the `finally` clause from your `using` isn't there at all, and it's a state machine<sup>2</sup> that relies on being in certain good (>= 0) states in order to make further progress forwards. (It's also illegal C#, but hey ho).

Now lets look at its `Dispose`:

```
[DebuggerHidden]
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    switch (this.<>1__state)
    {
        case -3:
        case 1:
            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                this.<>m__Finally1();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

So we can see the `<>m__Finally1` is called here (as well as due to exiting the `while` loop in `MoveNext`.

And `<>m__Finally1`:

```
private void <>m__Finally1()
{
    this.<>1__state = -1;
    if (this.<sillier>5__1 != null)
    {
        this.<sillier>5__1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So, we can see that `sillier` was disposed *and* we moved into a negative state which means that `MoveNext` doesn't have to do *any* special work to handle the "we've already been disposed state".

So,

> An Idea: there can be a if(disposed) yield break; after every yield return. now dispose method of silly enumerator will just have to set disposed = true and move the enumerator once to dispose all the required stuff.

Is completely unnecessary. Trust the compiler to transform the code so that it does all of the *logical* things it should - it just runs it's finally clause once, when it's either exhausted the iterator logic or when it's explicitly disposed.

---

<sup>1</sup>All code samples produced by .NET Reflector. But it's too good at decompiling these constructs these days so if you go and look at the `Silly` method itself:

```
[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<Silly>d__1)), Extension]
private static IEnumerable<T> Silly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    IEnumerator<T> <sillier>5__1;
    using (<sillier>5__1 = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (<sillier>5__1.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return <sillier>5__1.Current;
        }
    }
    <sillier>5__1 = null;
}
```

It's managed to hide most details about that state machine away again. You need to chase the type referenced by the `IteratorStateMachine` attribute to see all of the gritty bits shown above.

---

<sup>2</sup>Please also note that the compiler is under *no obligations* to produce a state machine to allow iterators to work. It's an implementation detail of the current C# compilers. The C# Specification places no restriction on *how* the compiler transforms the iterator, just on what the effects should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. so its the finally block that compiler will understand to take care of... so if I call a dispose method outside of a finally block that will not be called. finally block is awesome!